# WPGraphQL add nested / multiple Query for Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql

i am currently building a quite complex website and for the first time wanted to try WordPress as a headless CMS with a next.js frontend. For exposing data to the frontend i decided to use GraphQL (so i can learn it also).

The complexity in this website comes from the data i need to display. A simple example: I have movies, actors and also streaming portals as custom post types. Each for its own has some meta fields and will be displayed on the website.

But on a movies page i want to show which actors played a role in that movie and other way arount, on actors page in which movies he / her / it played. So for that i have a meta field on movies with actor IDs and on actor CPT a meta field with movie ID.

What i want to achieve is, to query this data with GraphQL. But in the WordPress context and with WPGraphQL i cant get id done... The Query should look something like this:

```
GetMoviesWithActors {
  movies {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        title,
        [... more movie details],
        actorId,
        actors (where: ID = actorID) {
          name and so on...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cant wrap my head around the concept. How can i achieve, what i want to achieve? Thats for nested queries.

I dont find any good tutorial or resource online where i can see how to solve this...

Can anyone explain how i can add the functionality i want to have? A good link to a resource would help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, that doesn't helped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I did get it going.

For nested queries, I used Custom taxonomies linked to the custom post type. I extend the taxonomies with advanced custom fields. So now I can query movies and have the actors as a custom taxonomy.

To add custom where arguments to get more detailed queries, I registered GraphQL types. Like this:

```
    // where: { movieProdCountry: "Germany" }
add_action('graphql_register_types', function () {
    $customposttype_graphql_single_name = "Movie";
    register_graphql_field('RootQueryTo' . $customposttype_graphql_single_name . 'ConnectionWhereArgs', 'movieProdCountry', [
        'type' => 'String',
        'description' => __('The production country of the movie to filter by', $textdomain),
    ]);
});

add_filter('graphql_post_object_connection_query_args', function ($query_args, $source, $args, $context, $info) {
    $post_object_id = $args['where']['movieProdCountry'];
    if (isset($post_object_id)) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => 'movie_prod_country',
                'value' => $post_object_id,
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ];
    }
    return $query_args;
}, 10, 5);
```

That's the approach I came up with, after consulting the official WPGraphQL Slack channel.